# Improve Performance of CSS url() with DataURI Image

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, cordova

I know I am doing something dumb, really, but please bear with me...

Ok. We have a Cordova generated iOS app which basically runs a **remote** website (not strictly a SPA, but only with a few full page reloads), that is, the web site is *not* some html files that are distributed together with the app, but a real site that running on a server. The site shows a lot of elements with `background: url(img/foo.png);` or `background-image: url(img/bar.png);` defined. Now we want to reduce the image request from the client, and if possible, also speed up the page rendering.

So what we have done so far is that we pre-packed ~200 images (c.a. 7 MiB) into the iOS app, extract it into `/Documents` by first run, and load them via the Cordova `File` plug-in.

The server side will provide two CSS files, one without any `url()` call in it (`without-bg.css`), and the other with only elements that have `url()` call in it (`only-bg.css`). `without-bg.css` will be loaded just as normal, while the `only-bg.css` will be retrieved by AJAX and processed like this:

```
var styleSheetConverted = styleSheetRaw.replace(
    /(url\()(.*?)(\))/gi,
    function(m, p1, p2, p3){
        if(p2.match(/https?:\/\//i)) return p1+p2+p3;
        var naked = p2.replace(/"/g, '');
        if(imgDataURIs.hasOwnProperty(naked)){
            return p1+imgDataURIs[naked]+p3;
        }
        return p1+p2+p3;
    }
);
$('head').append(
    '<style>' + styleSheetConverted + '</style>'
);
```

Basically, I am replacing all `url(path/to/img.png)` calls into `url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K <...> ErkJggg==`, i.e. the base64 encoded data URIs. The problem is that this new string is *huge*, at least 10 MiB, if not larger. The app takes at least five to ten seconds to actually show anything with background. And the several reloads are making it even worse.

So, how can I improve this dynamic CSS generating process to make the images load faster...?

Images are already been made into strips… (yes, after that we still have ~200 images).

Comment: datauris create heavy memory leaks if you reload them many times....but sometimes you need to do it that way. so you can cache them in websql or as full json file &/or use cache.manifest.

Comment: Why are you doing this with data URLs at all?  Why not just package the image files with your app and reference them with ordinary local URLs?

Comment: @Pointy because they wouldn't work…? Correct me if I am wrong, but how can I reference them in the CSS file, which comes from *remote*, not local?

Comment: @Metaphox I'm not 100% sure; absolute `file://` URLs are pretty ugly in Phonegap (and I think they're different between iOS and Android). You may be doing the best thing here, I guess, if you can't pre-package the data URLs on the server.

Comment: @Pointy pre-pack the image into data URL on the server would reduce the number of http requests, yes, but it too would make even more data being transferred through the wire.

I have tried several times with several variants of file:// URL, but didn't get it to work, which is expected due to the sandbox restriction…? Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: @cocco cache.manifest is actually our current solution, but is not really working well. Could you explain a bit more about why and how it leaks memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own embedded web server that runs from inside the app and use URLs like the following to load the image:

```
http://127.0.0.1/myimage.png
```

Still, I'm not sure this should be an app if it doesn't run offline and it doesn't utilize any native functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the WebResourceLoadDelegate, will try it right now. The app does utilize native functionality like barcode scanner and reading custom settings from iPad. It should really be a full native app, the functionality does require full time internet access though.

Comment: FYI `WebResourceLoadDelegate` is not available in iOS. Went with the embedded HTTP server.